# The stairs have waypoints on it to let an object move up/down the stairs but the stairs also have a Nav Mesh Obstacle component what can I do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Everything is working as it should but not as I want it to be.

I have two agent both have the Nav Mesh Agent component.
Each agent move to his own waypoints. The problem is that one agent should move around a stairs to get to his waypoint while the other agent should move up this stairs with his waypoin ts on the stairs.

But since the stairs have Nav Mesh Obstacle component so the first agent will go around the stairs and not collide in them when the second agent come close to the stairs he can't keep moving up the stairs since the Nav Mesh Obstacle component on the stairs blocking his way.

So I have a conflict here. I want the first agent to move around the stairs to his waypoint and I want the second agent to move up the stairs. What should I do in this situation ?

This is a screenshot of the agent that try to move up the stairs but can't :

[Agent cant keep moving on stairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRJIH.jpg)

And a screenshot of the stairs and the stairs inspector components :

[Stairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1E45.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make a new NavMeshAgent? [A Pic of Humanoid Navmesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onfhJ.png)

Adding a new type and then giving this new one the same properties of your one that can move up the stairs.

If this is not your case:
Instead of having an obstacle there try adding a limit to the angles that the one that avoids stairs can climb.

View the picture above to see the angles they can climb and change it to something more flat so that this Non-StairClimber cannot climb the angle of that staircase

Comment: Thank you for accepting this answer! I hope it helped and your game is looking very good so far!